# Rotating a Open GL camera correctly using GLM

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, camera, glm-math

I have a camera class, which is initialized like so:

```
CameraFP::CameraFP()  {
    this->aspect_ratio = 800.0f / 600.0f;
    this->fov = 45.0f;
    this->near_plane = 0.1f;
    this->far_plane = 1000.0f;
    this->position = glm::vec3(0, 0, 0);
    this->target = position + glm::vec3(0, 0, -1);
    this->up = glm::vec3(0, 1, 0);
    this->m_rotation = glm::mat4(1.0);

    m_view = glm::lookAt(position, target, up);
    m_projection = glm::perspective(fov, aspect_ratio, near_plane, far_plane);
}
```

And here are other functions of import:

```
void CameraFP::update(sf::Window *app)  {
    process_keyboard(app);
    process_mouse(app);

    calculate_view();
}

void CameraFP::process_keyboard(sf::Window *app)  {
    const sf::Input *input = &app->GetInput();

    up = m_rotation * glm::vec3(0, 1, 0);

    glm::vec3 forward = glm::vec3(0, 0, -1);
    glm::vec3 forward_rotated = m_rotation * forward;

    glm::vec3 right = glm::vec3(1, 0, 0);
    glm::vec3 right_rotated = m_rotation * right;

    if (input->IsKeyDown(sf::Key::W))  {
        position += forward_rotated;
    }
    if (input->IsKeyDown(sf::Key::S))  {
        position -= forward_rotated;
    }
    if (input->IsKeyDown(sf::Key::A))  {
        position -= right_rotated;
    }
    if (input->IsKeyDown(sf::Key::D))  {
        position += right_rotated;
    }
}

void CameraFP::process_mouse(sf::Window *app)  {
    // TODO: Make the below constants, and take framerate into account
    GLfloat SPEED_X = 0.000001f;
    GLfloat SPEED_Y = 0.000001f;

    GLfloat mouse_x = app->GetInput().GetMouseX();
    GLfloat mouse_y = app->GetInput().GetMouseY();

    GLfloat mouse_x_delta = old_mouse_x - mouse_x;
    GLfloat mouse_y_delta = old_mouse_y - mouse_y;

    if (mouse_x_delta != 0 ||
        mouse_y_delta != 0)  {
        if (mouse_x_delta != 0)  {
            y_rot += mouse_x_delta * SPEED_X;

            m_rotation = glm::rotate(m_rotation, y_rot, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
        }
        if (mouse_y_delta != 0)  {
            x_rot += mouse_y_delta * SPEED_Y;

            m_rotation = glm::rotate(m_rotation, x_rot, glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));;
        }
    }

    this->old_mouse_x = mouse_x;
    this->old_mouse_y = mouse_y;

    app->SetCursorPosition(app->GetWidth() / 2, app->GetHeight() / 2);
}


void CameraFP::calculate_view()  {
    glm::vec3 forward = glm::vec3(0, 0, -1);
    glm::vec3 forward_rotated = m_rotation * forward;

    target = position += glm::normalize(forward_rotated);

    m_view = glm::lookAt(position, target, up);
}
```

My problem is that when I compile the project, the compiler outputs an error saying:

```
\CameraFP.cpp|59|error: no match for 'operator*' in '((CameraFP*)this)->CameraFP::m_rotation * glm::detail::tvec3<float>(((const int&)((const int*)(&0))), ((const int&)((const int*)(&1))), ((const int&)((const int*)(&0))))'|
```

From what I understand vec = mat4 * vec should yield a rotated vector? Since I haven't been able to test this code, I don't know if the function work correctly.

**Edit**

Updated code according to the comments and awnsers. My problem is now that I get a BSOD, somewhere in the render function...

```
void CameraFP::process_keyboard(sf::Window *app)  {
    const sf::Input *input = &app->GetInput();

    up = m_rotation * glm::vec4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glm::vec4 forward = glm::vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    glm::vec4 forward_rotated = m_rotation * forward;

    glm::vec4 right = glm::vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glm::vec4 right_rotated = m_rotation * right;

    if (input->IsKeyDown(sf::Key::W))  {
        position += forward_rotated;
    }
    if (input->IsKeyDown(sf::Key::S))  {
        position -= forward_rotated;
    }
    if (input->IsKeyDown(sf::Key::A))  {
        position -= right_rotated;
    }
    if (input->IsKeyDown(sf::Key::D))  {
        position += right_rotated;
    }
}

void CameraFP::process_mouse(sf::Window *app)  {
    // TODO: Make the below constants, and take framerate into account
    GLfloat SPEED_X = 0.000001f;
    GLfloat SPEED_Y = 0.000001f;

    GLfloat mouse_x = app->GetInput().GetMouseX();
    GLfloat mouse_y = app->GetInput().GetMouseY();

    GLfloat mouse_x_delta = old_mouse_x - mouse_x;
    GLfloat mouse_y_delta = old_mouse_y - mouse_y;

    if (mouse_x_delta != 0 ||
        mouse_y_delta != 0)  {
        if (mouse_x_delta != 0)  {
            y_rot += mouse_x_delta * SPEED_X;

            m_rotation = glm::rotate(m_rotation, y_rot, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
        }
        if (mouse_y_delta != 0)  {
            x_rot += mouse_y_delta * SPEED_Y;

            m_rotation = glm::rotate(m_rotation, x_rot, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));;
        }
    }

    this->old_mouse_x = mouse_x;
    this->old_mouse_y = mouse_y;

    app->SetCursorPosition(app->GetWidth() / 2, app->GetHeight() / 2);
}

void CameraFP::calculate_view()  {
    glm::vec4 forward = glm::vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    glm::vec4 forward_rotated = m_rotation * forward;

    target = position += forward_rotated;

    m_view = glm::lookAt(v4tov3(position), v4tov3(target), v4tov3(up));
}

glm::vec3 v4tov3(glm::vec4 v1)  {
    return glm::vec3(v1.x, v1.y, v1.z);
}
```

**Edit 2**

Problem now is with the camera rotation with the mouse, it just doesn't work, for some reason changes on the x axis oft times effect change on the y and vice versa. In addition, if I move the mouse right or left on the x axis (y rotation) the camera rotates left...

```
void CameraFP::process_mouse(sf::Clock *clock, sf::Window *app)  {
    // TODO: Make the below constants, and take framerate into account
    GLfloat SPEED_X = 0.25f;
    GLfloat SPEED_Y = 0.25f;

    GLfloat screen_x = app->GetWidth();
    GLfloat screen_y = app->GetHeight();

    GLfloat mouse_x = float(screen_x / 2 - app->GetInput().GetMouseX());
    GLfloat mouse_y = float(screen_y / 2 - app->GetInput().GetMouseY());

    GLfloat mouse_x_delta = old_mouse_x - mouse_x;
    GLfloat mouse_y_delta = old_mouse_y - mouse_y;

    GLfloat current_time = clock->GetElapsedTime();
    GLfloat delta_time = current_time - last_time;

    this->last_time = current_time;

    if (mouse_x_delta != 0 ||
        mouse_y_delta != 0)  {
        if (mouse_x_delta != 0)  {
            y_rot += glm::radians(delta_time * SPEED_X * mouse_x);

            m_rotation = glm::rotate(m_rotation, y_rot, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

            std::cout << "Y Rotation: " << y_rot << "\n";
        }
        if (mouse_y_delta != 0)  {
            x_rot += glm::radians(delta_time * SPEED_Y * mouse_y);

            m_rotation = glm::rotate(m_rotation, x_rot, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

            std::cout << "X rotation: " << x_rot << "\n";
        }
    }

    app->SetCursorPosition(screen_x / 2, screen_y / 2);

    this->old_mouse_x = float(screen_x / 2 - app->GetInput().GetMouseX());
    this->old_mouse_y = float(screen_y / 2 - app->GetInput().GetMouseY());
}
```

Comment: The operator * for mat4*vec3 is not found. `m_rotation` is a `mat4` and `forward` is a `vec3`. I think it should be a `vec4`.

Comment: @AquilaRapax But, aren't I meant to represent positions as vec3s? I don't think I should keep casting between glm::vec3 and glm::vec4 all the time. Should I be using a glm::mat3 to represent my rotation?

Comment: Normally homogeneous coordinates are used, and thus all vectors and matrices have a dimension of 4. For vectors the last coordinate is called `w`-coordinate and have to be 1. So you don't need to cast vec3 to vec4. Just use vec4 and set the 4th coordinate to 1. For further informations have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace all glm::vec3(0, 1, 0); by glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

As for the vec-mac multiplication, AquilaRapax is right in that you can only multiply a mat4 with a vec4. But since you're multiplying directions, the 4rth coordinate should be 0.0f, not 1.0f. This will have the effect to ignore the translations (1.0 will teke them into account, which you don't want)

See http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/ for details on matrices.

However, it's often a good idea to keep vec3 instead of vec4's, mostly for clarity purposes (i.e., glm::vec3 mPosition instead of glm::vec4 mPosition). It is thus handy to have 2 functions like these (untested) :

```
glm::vec3 TransformDirection(glm::vec3 pDirection, glm::mat4 pMatrix){
    return pMatrix * glm::vec4(pDirection, 0.0f);
}

glm::vec3 TransformPosition(glm::vec3 pDirection, glm::mat4 pMatrix){
    return pMatrix * glm::vec4(pDirection, 1.0f);
}
```

Comment: @Calvin1602 So I'll have to make my position (and all my other vectors) vec4? Since I need to transform, for example, the forward vector by the rotation matrix, then I need to apply the rotated vector to the position. And in the case for the directions I'll have to put the 0.0f as the last parameter, and for the position and targets, 1.0f?

Comment: @Calvin1602 eg. in the calculate_view function I'll have to something like this: http://pastebin.com/6F0gh8dG ... My computer crashes when I run that :|

Comment: @Calvin1602 Wow! It doesn't give me a BSOD! Thanks... My problem now seems to be the mouse, no matter what direction I move the mouse on the x axis I always turn right, and no matter what direction I move the mouse on the y axis, it always looks downwards... mmm...

Comment: See edits. For the mouse : old_mouse is buggy. Remove it completely and use dimensions/2 instead. Or remove SetCursorPosition().

Comment: @Calvin1602 Okay, done that. I'm even more confused now, because when I move the mouse left it moves me right! And when I move it right it moves the camera down... I am really confused... http://pastebin.com/PyVYC9X1

Comment: Cool, thanks for the link! The code works, however, I don't understand exactly how...

Comment: corresponding tutorial : http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-6-keyboard-and-mouse/

Answer (score 0):

At the end of `process::mouse` you save the coordinates in `old_mouse_x` and `old_mouse_y` but then you move the cursor to the middle of the screen. If you do this `old_mouse_x` and `old_mouse_y` becomes invalid. What you need to do is set these variables after repositioning the cursor:

```
app->SetCursorPosition(app->GetWidth() / 2, app->GetHeight() / 2);
this->old_mouse_x = app->GetWidth() / 2;
this->old_mouse_y = app->GetHeight() / 2;
```